# Positioning an image in CSS

Tags: css

Basically, I have a navigation bar in my website. In the centre of the nav bar, I want my website's name centred. This was easy of course, but now I want my website's logo positioned to the left of it. Float: left does not work, as this simply puts the logo on the far left of the nav bar.

```
<!doctype html> 
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            *
            {
            margin: 0em;
            padding: 0em;
            }
            #container {
            width:100%;
            border:1px solid #999;
            margin:0px auto 0;
            overflow:hidden;
            background: gray;
            }
            #name {
            text-align: center;
            position: relative;
            }
            #top-left {
            position: relative;
            float: left;
            border: 1px solid black;
            }
            #top-right {
            float:right;
            margin-bottom:10px;
            }
            #bottom-right {
            float:right;
            clear:both;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <img id="top-left" src="http://www.webmasterworld.com/gfx/logo.png" alt="">
            <img id="top-right" src="http://www.pubcon.com/exhibitor/gfx/markethealth.gif" alt="">
            <img id="bottom-right" src="http://www.webmasterworld.com/theme/default/gfx/donate1.gif" alt="">
            <h1 id="name">champion</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would create a new `div style`, and use this to put your image where you need it. Saying that, please add your code (cut it down to the problem code if the code is more than 50 lines), because it will be easier for us to give you an answer.

Comment: i tried putting my code but it wouldn't let me!

Comment: May also want to try using css-validator, see if there is anything wrong with your css file.  It isn't always right, but it helps a lot I have found.

Comment: can you check now i fixed it

Comment: Just ran it through the validator, says nothing is wrong with the new css.  Can you give the website url so I can test the whole thing?  Or you can do it yourself at w3c css-validator site.

Comment: You seem to have a `</html>` with no opening tag. Please fix this.

Comment: Just noticed that myself.  As I said, the validator isn't perfect.

Comment: @cluemein What validator did you use? I ran it through the W3 validator, and got these errors: `Line 1, Column 1: no document type declaration; will parse without validation`, `Line 37, Column 10: document type does not allow element "BODY" here`, ` Line 45, Column 7: end tag for element "HTML" which is not open`.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the css! I just need help with poisitioning my logo without absolute because absolute is fixed and i dont want fixed!

Comment: @zyboxinternational Odd, I used the same validator.

Comment: @user3777060 I am not sure I understand what you are asking then. Sorry

Comment: @user3777060  It may not be the fix your looking for, but your css looks much nicer now.

Comment: well can you help me then

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do something like this. It uses `:before` to attach the logo to the heading text: http://codepen.io/pageaffairs/pen/bchLo

```
<!doctype html> 
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            *
            {
            margin: 0em;
            padding: 0em;
            }

            #container {
            width:100%;
            border:1px solid #999;
            margin:0px auto 0;
            overflow:hidden;
            background: gray;
            text-align: center;
            }

            #name {
            line-height: 56px;
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            }

            #top-right {
            float:right;
            margin-bottom:10px;
            }

            #bottom-right {
            float:right;
            clear:both;
            }

            h1 span {
                position: relative;
                display: inline-block;
                padding: 0 20px;
            }

            h1 span:before {
                content: "";
                width: 109px;
                height: 56px;
                background: url(http://www.webmasterworld.com/gfx/logo.png);
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                right: 100%;
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <img id="top-right" src="http://www.pubcon.com/exhibitor/gfx/markethealth.gif" alt="">
            <img id="bottom-right" src="http://www.webmasterworld.com/theme/default/gfx/donate1.gif" alt="">
            <h1 id="name"><span>champion</span></h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: listen man that works but what if I vertical-align the text? then the logo no longer follows it. How can i fix that?

Comment: Perhaps post a CodePen of what you mean, like I did, as it's not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @ralph.m Do not spam other answers, claiming your answer is the best.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this trick:

```
<table style="background-color:Gray; width:100%;" >     
    <tr>        
      <td style="text-align:right; width:45%">
        <img id="top-left" src="http://www.webmasterworld.com/gfx/logo.png" alt="">
      </td>
      <td style="text-align:left;  width:30%""> 
            <h1 id="name">champion</h1>
      </td>
      <td style="text-align:right; width:25%;">
        <img id="top-right" src="http://www.pubcon.com/exhibitor/gfx/markethealth.gif" alt="">
      </td>
    </tr>       
    <tr style="text-align:right;"> 
       <td colspan="3">
        <img id="bottom-right" src="http://www.webmasterworld.com/theme/default/gfx/donate1.gif" alt="">
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @ralph.m On other answers, do not attempt to claim that your answer is better, like you just did. This answer works, it may not be the simplest, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I have it running here where the `float: left` appears to be working. I'm guessing there may be something I'm missing. Could you put a jsfiddle or show a live example by chance.

[Here's what I see](http://jsfiddle.net/jeremyhawes/57CdX/)